# Is it possible to design the gain Kp for the system in the image, given it is underdamped and has a settling time of 2 seconds. Thank you

Tags: control-engineering, dynamics

[image: control system with proportional control]

$$G(s) = \frac{K_P}{(s+2)^2}$$
$$H(s) = s+4$$

I keep getting Kp = 0 which leads to a damping ratio of 1 which isn't underdamped. To find Kp = 0, I found the closed loop transfer function and compared the characteristic equation denominator to the standard closed loop characteristic equation and used the fact that for an underdamped system at settling time 2, $t_s$ the settling time is equal to $4/(\xi \cdot \omega_{\text{natural}})$.

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've seen splane diagrams where you plot poles and zeros though I'm not familiar with the method. To clarify, I was trying to find Kp given ξ(damping ratio) was less than 1 (underdamped), there isn't a ξdesired or ωdesired stated in question. To get from 2ξω=4+KP to  4=4+KP I used the formula we were taught which says for an underdamped second order response, the settling time is approximately equal to 4/ξω. In the question it was said that settling time was 2 so I rearranged this formula to given ξω = 4/settling time = 4/2 = 2, so 2ξω is 4.

Comment: It says exactly 2s, and that system is underdamped, I'm assuming the question has to be wrong then and since Kp = zero the open loop transfer function becomes 1/((s+2)^2). Thank you for the help.

Comment: Isn't the open loop transfer function Kp * 1/(s+2)^2, where 1/(s+2)^2 is the plant transfer function, the question doesn't say that but I assume since Kp is a gain it is applied to the plant transfer function 1/(s+2)^2 or is that not possible?

Comment: Yes and it is zero if $K_P$ is zero. See the block diagram. No signal passes through when $K_P=0$.

Comment: Oh right, yeah, I was getting confused the difference between no proportional control (Kp doesn't exist) and proportional control where Kp = 0

Comment: If you (later) find out what the expected answer was (or a correction in the question), please post it as an answer below to help others who may visit this question in the future.

Comment: Yes will do, thank you!